# Solving an equation $x + x^{0.925} = 15$

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to solve this equation for a couple of days now but am getting stuck.

$x + x^{0.925} = 15$, find $x$.

I went in the direction of taking log on both sides of the equation but that does not help and I cannot simplify further. Also, I started substituting values to find a range within which it might fall but am thinking there should be a better way to do that.

Any suggestions how to go about it. I just need a clue and I can work it out then.

Comment: One could try Newton's Method.  Your tag says "Calculus"--If you're in CalcI, Newton's method could be the way to go.  Because Wolfram Alpha only gives a numeric solution, I would say this is the route to take.

Comment: To begin with: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Bx%5E%280.925%29%3D15

Comment: According to Mathematica there isn't a closed form for the solution.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: You can use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that the real solution is between $8$ and $9$, say.

Comment: The exponent is a rational number ($37/40$), so maybe you wind up with an equation like $x^{40} + x^{37} = 15^{40}$.

Comment: @rlgordonma: not quite.  If $y = x^{1/40}$ you get
$y^{40} + y^{37} = 15$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I see, then you have to raise your solution to the 40th power.  Fun all around!

Comment: @rlgordonma I was gonna ask next how do you solve that?

Comment: @GauravSinha: good question!  Newton's method, perhaps, although the high degree is cause for concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's study the function $f(x)=x+x^{0.925}-15$, on its domain $(0,+\infty)$.

The derivative is $f'(x)=1+0.925x^{-0.075}$, which is positive for all $x>0$.

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=-15$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$, it follows that $f$ is a bijection from $(0,+\infty)$ onto $(-15,+\infty)$.

In particular, there exists a unique $x>0$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Now $f(8)=-0.16...$ and $f(9)=1.63...$, so your zero is somewhere between $8$ and $9$.

If you want more precision, use the bisection algorithm.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Thanks for the edit. Some people call the bisection method/algorithm the dichotomy method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.  Since 0.925 is close to 1, x should be little higher than 15/2.  Assume 8.  Expand x^{0.925} around  8, i.e.  $8^{0.925} + 0.925*8^{-0.075}(x-8)$.  Now the equation becomes $x+6.84476+0.79143(x-8) \approx 15$.  Solve x.